# Prompting user input in selenium web driver before launching URL

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to take user input then stored into the variable and i want to use that input into my program .

Here is my code , code is asking for user input but not loading the URL . It is just initiating the driver. Please someone correct me .

**Current behavior:**

1. Initiating the driver (IE shows the message " This is the Initial start page for wendriver server"
2. Asking for prompt .I gave my input in the prompt and click OK.
   thats it .. after that code is not getting executed. Please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whLEa.png)

```
    public class app{   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Automation\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.promptResponse=prompt('Please enter the USER ID')");

    if(isAlertPresent(driver)) {
        // switch to alert
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        // sleep to allow user to input text
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // this doesn't seem to work 
        alert.accept();
        String ID = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");


    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.get("my application URL");
    driver.findElement(By.name("USERID")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("user_pwd")).sendKeys("mypwd");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).submit();
    .......
    ......
    // some more code which is doing my application fucntionality
    .......
    ......
    ........

    private static boolean isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver) {
         try 
            { 
                driver.switchTo().alert(); 
                return true; 
            }   // try 
            catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
            { 
                return false; 
            }
    }

    }
```

Comment: `IE shows the message " This is the Initial start page for wendriver server"` is OK with me. But where do you find the `Alert` or the `User input prompt` ? Can you share a snapshot of the same?

Comment: Added Screenshot. Let me know if u not able to view

Comment: What happens if you manually accept the prompt rather than using `alert.accept()`?

Comment: If click on OK by manually , IE exists with above message(driver server message). After that Nothing is happening :(. same

Comment: I think you are working behind a proxy, you may need to disable the proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code; it should serve your purpose:

```
public class app{   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Automation\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.promptResponse=prompt('Please enter the USER ID')");

    isAlertPresent(driver);

    String ID = (String) js.executeScript("return window.promptResponse");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.get("my application URL");
    driver.findElement(By.name("USERID")).sendKeys("username");
    driver.findElement(By.name("user_pwd")).sendKeys("mypwd");
    driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).submit();
    }

    private static void isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver) {
        try 
           { 
               driver.switchTo().alert(); 
               driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // even though not needed

               isAlertPresent(driver);
           }   // try 
           catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) 
           { 

           }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take input (ie. URL) from promp then you may use `JOptionPane`'s `showInputDialog()` method from Java Swing.

**Code snippet:**

```
 String URL =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter URL");
```